# Extend the "Convert to Blocks" feature to add additional functionality

Tags: block-editor

We are in the process of migrating over a decade of content on hundreds of sites to the Gutenberg block editor. We had been using lots of custom shortcodes and are developing blocks to replace them.

I would love to perform additional find/replace kind of stuff to convert our old shortcodes to our new block markup when someone click "Convert to Blocks".

For example, I would like "Convert to Blocks" to look for things like [my_custom_shortcode] and replace it with the appropriate custom block markup.

Does WordPress provide any filters or options for adding my own conversion functions to part of the "Convert to Blocks" functionality? or any other ideas to tie into this?

Comment: Have a look at the Block Transforms API in the handbook that explains exactly this: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-transforms/#shortcode

Comment: Maybe a bit off topic: For a similar scenario we skipped the "convert to blocks" altogether and did the following: Get the `post_content` of each post, parse it and replace the old parts with the correct HTML markup for the new block (HTML comment and such). You'll have to know how WP stores this specific block inside the post content, then it can work quite nicely.